# Codeigniter ion auth user management while create a new user

Tags: codeigniter

Hope you guys are fine. I am in a little problem. I am not expert in Codeigniter.
I have 5 user groups like super_admin, admin, reseller, agent and general. while super_admin will create a user he can give all access to the new user. but an admin can give reseller, agent and general. Reseller can agent and general and finally agent cant only general access. Now want to hide those user group name from a drop-down menu which has not permission of a user.
My code is below. I wrote the code in a `create_user.php` page. Please help me.

```
    <?php                                     
      foreach ($groups as $group):
          $a=$this->ion_auth->get_users_groups()->row()->name;
        if(!in_array($group->name, $a)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $group['id']; ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($group['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></option>
   <?php } endforeach ?>
   </select>  
  </div>
?php endif ?>
```

Comment: show db table entries for groups

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that you can test.

Few assumptions are taken that should be readily apparent like consecutive ids and that `super_admin` is id 5.

The relevant `ion_auth` functions are commented out.

```
<?php

$groups = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'general'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'agent'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'reseller'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'admin'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'super_admin'
    ),
);

//$groups = $this->ion_auth->groups()->result_array();

array_pop($groups); // remove super_admin (last element) from array

$curr_user_group = 4;

//$curr_user_group = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups()->row()->id;

$user_create_groups = $curr_user_group - 1;

$groups = array_slice($groups, 0, $user_create_groups);

echo '<pre>';

foreach ($groups as $group) {

    print_r($group);

}
```

As general can't create a group lower the `$groups` array will be blank for it. Hopefully you have thought of this and have some system in place so a user with that group can't create users. Also note that you need to institute a similar validation function on the backend to make sure users don't elevate themselves or others to `super_admin` by changing the select box in their browser.